# If Jesus is "a god" would not Jehovah’s Witnesses be polytheists?

Tags: christology, gospel-of-john, jehovahs-witnesses

> Isaiah 44:6, Thus says the Lord, the King of Israel And His Redeemer, the Lord of host; I am the first and I am the last, AND THERE IS NO GOD BESIDES ME.
>
> Isaiah 44:24, Thus says the Lord your Redeemer, and the one who formed you from the womb, I. the Lord, am the maker of all things BY MYSELF, And spreading out the heavens BY MYSELF.
>
> Isaiah 45:5, I am the Lord and THERE IS NO OTHER; BESIDES ME THERE IS NO GOD."

Now that it’s established that there is no other God, then why do Jehovah’s Witnesses teach that Jesus Christ is "a god" according to their NWT of the Bible at John 1:1? They explain their position here: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1984647#h=18

So the specific question I'm asking is as follows: is Jesus Christ a true god, or a false god?

> John 17:3, "And this is eternal life, that they may know Thee, THE ONLY TRUE GOD, and Jesus Christ whom Thou has sent." John 5:44, "How can you believe, when you receive glory from one another, and you do not seek the glory that is FROM THE ONLY GOD?"

If there is only one true something, then everything else is false. The Apostle Paul speaks about this at 1 Corinthians 8:5-6:

> For even if there are so-called gods whether in heaven or on earth as indeed there are many gods and many lords, yet for us there is one God, the Father, from whom are all things, and we exist for Him; and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we exist through Him.

So in view of the following statement, "Jehovah’s Witnesses do not deny Jesus’ godship, or divinity" "Jesus himself said that he lived in heaven before being born as a human. As a spirit creature in heaven, Jesus had a special relationship with Jehovah." "He is called the firstborn of all creation, for he was God's first creation. "This means that Jesus is the only one directly created by God.

Again, is this first spirit creature created by God and described as "a god" at John 1:1 a true god or a false god, and what is his nature? Galatians 4:8, "However at that time, when you did not know God, you were slaves to those WHICH BY NATURE ARE NO gods." Some of the information is from the following site.
https://answersingenesis.org/jesus/jesus-is-god/is-jesus-the-creator-god/

Answer (score 8):

**Do Jehovah’s Witnesses consider themselves to be polytheists?**  No, because they do not worship Jesus.  They worship only Jehovah God.  Jesus is not the Almighty God, but is merely “a god” who was created by Jehovah as a mighty spirit creature.  He is divine but he is inferior to Jehovah God.  Here is the official Jehovah’s Witness view from the February 2006 Awake article, The Bible’s Viewpoint: Is There Only One True God?

> Jesus, the Angels, and the Devil: The Scriptures do at times refer to actual persons as gods. However, a careful examination clearly reveals that the term “god” in these instances is not intended to designate these individuals as deities. Rather, in the original languages in which the Bible was written, the term “god” was also used to describe a mighty person or an individual who is divine or closely associated with the Almighty God.  For example, some Bible verses allude to Jesus Christ as a god. (Isaiah 9:6, 7; John 1:1, 18) Does this mean that Jesus is to be worshipped? Jesus himself said: “It is Jehovah your God you must worship, and it is to him alone you must render sacred service.” (Luke 4:8) Clearly, although Jesus is mighty in power and divine in nature, the Bible does not portray him as an object of worship.  Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102006049

**Is Jesus a true god or a false god?** Here is their explanation as given in Questions From Readers 1986: ▪ How could Jesus be “a god” who was created by Jehovah when in Isaiah 43:10 Jehovah says: “Before me there was no God formed, and after me there continued to be none”?

> The Lord Jesus Christ is no false god, no demon god, no mere idol. He ‘is the reflection of Jehovah God’s glory.’ (Hebrews 1:3) Thus it is fitting for John 1:1 to acknowledge Jesus as “a god,” or “godlike” (Johannes Schneider).  Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1986491

**Is this first spirit creature created by God and described as "a god" at John 1:1 a true god or a false god, and what is his nature?**  Now we come to the real issue – the Jehovah’s Witness belief that Jehovah created Jesus as a mighty spirit creature.  If they are right, then the nature of Jesus must be that of a created angel (who they say is known in heaven as Michael the Archangel).  And the Bible says we must not worship any created angel (Revelation 19:10). Therefore, if Jesus is a created spirit creature then the Witnesses do right not to worship him.

But the Bible also says that God has never called any created angel his Son, or claimed to be his Father (Hebrews 1:5).

Yet all God’s angels are told to worship his Son (Hebrews 1:6).

Was Jesus created before coming to earth? That is the only question that demands our attention when establishing who Jesus REALLY is.  But you have not asked that question in such a way that Trinitarian Christians can answer from the Bible.

Comment: _"Do Jehovah’s Witnesses consider themselves to be polytheists? No, because they do not worship Jesus"_ By this logic, a village in ancient Greece which believed in the existence of all the Greek gods but only actively worshipped Poseidon would be considered a monotheistic society. Polytheism doesn't necessitate that you have to _worship_ more than one god. A belief system that acknowledges the existence of more than one "god" (with or without the capital "G") is sufficient for that belief system to be polytheistic in the strictest terms.

Comment: Excellent point.  Please realise that I am not expressing my own, personal opinion here, but simply quoting from official Jehovah's Witneess sources on how THEY respond to the accusation of polytheism. The fact they see Jesus as a created being arises because they are anti-trinitarian. But, yes, polytheism can be defined as belief in more than one God (with or without a capital G).

Comment: @Abion47  simply believing that there is more than one personage that can be called god or a god does not constitute polytheism.  2 Cor 4:4 calls  Satan the god of this world. Are Christians who believe that verse polytheist?

Comment: @Kris If there are Christian sects that take that verse to be literal (and there are many Christian sects that take many scriptural verses literally that others might argue should be taken figuratively or metaphorically), then they acknowledge that Satan is, in some form or other, a god in his own right. And yes, I would say that satisfies the definition of polytheism in the strictest sense.

Comment: @Abion47 and did the Jewish people spoken of by Jesus who called some of the prophets gods,   Psalms 82:6 and referenced by Jesus in John 10:34-36, practice polytheism?

Comment: @Kris The definition of polytheism is the belief in, or worship of, more than one god. So to answer your question and any future questions you may have lined up, if a group of people truly believes in the existence of multiple gods, then regardless of how many of those gods they actually worship, that is the definition of polytheism. (This is of course also dependent on taking the term "god" literally as opposed to figuratively or metaphorically, e.g. "that man is a god among men".)

Comment: @Abion47  I agree with that. The fact that JWs do not worship Jesus shows that they do not believe he is GOD. However we do believe John 1:1 is commenting on the quality rather than the identity of “the Word”. Thus we agree with translations that say “the Word was devine.  We are monotheists. Not henotheists not kathenotheists not polytheists. We state unequivocally that Jehovah alone is eternal and uncreated.

Comment: @Kris Just because they do not believe Jesus is God (capital G) doesn't mean they do not believe he is _a_ god. And just because they don't worship him as such doesn't mean they _don't_ believe he is a god. I am not talking about whether JWs believe in the concept of the Holy Trinity since it's clear that they don't. Jesus is not "the Almighty God", that much is clear in their doctrine. Now, do JWs believe Jesus is a god in his own right (even if he is not the target of active worship)? That is the _only_ question that matters when it comes to classifying their status as polytheists.

Comment: And to differentiate between polytheism and henotheism here, polytheism is where the doctrine of a religion states that other gods exist, whereas henotheism merely does not write off the possibility that other gods exist. If JWs believe that Jesus is a god in his own right, that makes them polytheists, not henotheists, since the doctrine is unequivocally stating the existence of another god without any ambiguity. (It is also debatable whether or not there is some amount of overlap between polytheism and henotheism.)

Comment: http://defendingjehovahswitnesses.blogspot.com/2013/01/do-jehovahs-witnesses-really-follow.html.   I find this helpful.

Comment: https://biblehub.com/hebrew/430.htm

Comment: The above link helps in understanding the many different ways the word god in the Bible can be applied. JWs use the name Jehovah for the one eternally existing Almighty One. Anytime the word god is used for another creature in heaven or on earth it is describing the elevated position that creature holds in relation to lesser ones.

Comment: @Kris That still doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

No, of course Jehovah's Witnesses do not consider themselves to be polytheists. That is because they make sure they do not give any worship to Jesus Christ. It is strictly 'taboo' for any JW to pray to Jesus (as prayer is an act of worship), or to bow down on one's knees or to prostrate themselves in the name of Jesus (which is an act of worship). They speak of metaphoric 'bowing down' in Jesus' name, but it must never be literal. They speak of an attitude of respect to Jesus but ensure that that never becomes a worshipful attitude. They speak of obedience to Jesus' commands as a sign of their respect for him but at every point, their respect for, and honour of Jehovah God must always be greater than that which they have for Jesus Christ, because they maintain that Jehovah created Jesus as a separate being, distinct from himself. They know the Bible condemns polytheism, or even worship of more than one God, so they are at pains to stress that they never worship Jesus either as God, or as 'a god'.

To demonstrate their stance on refusing to pray to Jesus, consider their treatment of Acts 7 verse 59 which says, "While they were stoning him, Stephen prayed, 'Lord Jesus, receive my spirit'." But JWs have been told that no, Stephen was NOT praying to Jesus. That is why their NWT renders this verse as, "And they went on casting stones at Stephen as he made appeal and said: 'Lord Jesus, receive my spirit'."

Notice how the word 'prayer' is avoided? The Greek word for "calling upon" is in the text used by the JWs. However, all JWs know that Jesus was not physically present when Stephen called upon him after having had a vision of both God and Jesus. They know the resurrected Christ was in heaven. They also know that the only way you can call upon God or Christ, who are not physically present, is to pray to them. Here is what their *Insight on the Scriptures says, Vol. II p 667*:

> "The entire Scriptural record testifies that Jehovah is the One to
>   whom prayer should be directed... Though some claim that prayer may
>   properly be addressed to others, such as to God's Son, the evidence is
>   emphatically to the contrary. True, there are rare instances in which
>   words are addressed to Jesus Christ in heaven. Stephen, when about to
>   die, appealed to Jesus, saying, "Lord Jesus, receive my spirit." (Ac
>   7:59) However, the context reveals a circumstance giving basis for
>   this exceptional expression. Stephen at that very time had a vision of
>   'Jesus standing at God's right hand,' and evidently reacting as if he
>   were in Jesus' presence, he felt free to speak this plea to the one
>   whom he recognized as the head of the Christian congregation."

So although the JWs admit Stephen was calling out to Jesus in heaven, they refuse to say it was a prayer to Jesus.

I will not give further quotes on the other points, for I am quietly confident that JWs will be eager to provide ample quotes from their official web-site that will conclusively show that they are confident their refusal to worship Christ to any degree whatsoever does not contradict them giving him a merely titular ascription of being "a god". Although it is worship that differentiates deity from creatures, JWs believe that simply giving Jesus a title of "a god", while ensuring their respect for him always stops short of worship, overcomes this theological problem of the Bible calling Christ "the Mighty God" (Isaiah 9:6) and (in their NWT) "a god" in John 1:1, despite verse 3 stating that he "made everything that was made".

As for the specific question you ask: "is Jesus Christ a true god, or a false god?" - JWs would never say Jesus must therefore be a false god (given your points). They think Jesus is 'a mighty one' and would argue that 'god' in lower case refers to that, without that 'mighty one' requiring any worship. It might be worth asking a further question on why, then, Jehovah God is ALSO called "the Mighty God" in Isaiah 10:21, a few verses on from the Son being given that same accolade.

Comment: Although the title seems to ask about polytheism, the Op sweeps that aside in the body of the question and then asks two questions: 1) ridiculously asks is Jesus a true or false god? You answered that one. 2) what is Jesus’ nature? That one remains unanswered.

Comment: This answer skirts around the nature of the question. Whether or not JWs actively worship Jesus doesn't strictly matter. The only real important question is this: do JWs believe that Jesus is a god (even if he is not God with a capital "G")?

Comment: I find this answer pretty clear: no, Jesus is not a god for JWs. After all, he is not even God for them. :) And it's for the very fear of *being* polytheists that JWs consider that Jesus is not God nor a god.

Comment: The tone of your answer seems very sarcastic, as if JWs contradict themselves by differentiating between a "calling upon" Jesus and a "prayer" to God. But this is in no way different from more mainstream Christian branches. E.g. Orthodox Christians "pray" to saints and Mother Mary, in the understanding that they only ask them to pass on their prayers to God.

Comment: All power authority of all things given to Jesus Christ. So, pray to Him. And every knees shall bow and every mouths shall confess that Jesus is Lord.

Comment: Just always skirt around the theological problems with their belief on the trinity...if one doesnt worship Jesus, and we worship our creator, how then does one reconcile that JWS believe Jesus created this world? We worship our creator...that's clearly Christ in the Bible. Also, how can we pray to an active life force...how can Jesus send us an ative life force described as He? That is absurd. This answer is incomplete -1 from me.

Comment: @Adam I'm not a JW but know a great deal about them, esp. how they disagree with the Trinity doctrine. I have given a neutral answer to show how they 'deal with' the problem of saying with their lips that Jesus is "a god" without giving their Jesus any worship, adoration or praying to him etc. This is how they get round that problem, to their own satisfaction, and it has to be said that if Jesus is not worshipped by them in any way, they are only offering  their worship to Jehovah God. So, they cannot be polytheists but calling Jesus 'a god' then means something different to them than to us.

Comment: So Thomas falling to his knees before the resurrected Christ saying my lord and my God is not an act of worship given that Daniels friends refused to kneel before Nebuchadnezzars golden statue citing that would be an intentional act of worship?

Comment: @Adam  Of course Thomas worshipped the risen Christ! But JWs say he did not. I say he did. I am not a JW.

Comment: @Anne...you do realise JWs believe Jesus created this world yes? As far as I understand it, I have a couple of close friends who are jw, they have no problem worshipping through Christ. The problem was, their church founder Russel wrote that they should worship Christ and this was the case up until about 1954. Given their monotheistic beliefs, this practise was altered citing to continue to do it would make them idolaters.  https://www.jwfacts.com/watchtower/worship-jesus.php