# According to Jehovah’s Witnesses what does the name Immanuel mean in light of their belief that Jesus is a created being and not God?

Tags: christology, gospel-of-matthew, jehovahs-witnesses, names-of-god, isaiah

[This article](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1988404) goes on to say,

> Without accurate knowledge, we may become ensnared by false teachings promoted by God's opposer, Satan the Devil. Therefore, if a doctrine contradicts God's Word, if it is a lie, then believing it and teaching it discredits Jehovah and brings us into opposition to him. So we need to examine the Scriptures carefully to distinguish truth from falsehood.

They quote Acts 17:11.

> Now these were more noble minded than those in Thessalonica, for they received the word great eagerness, examining the Scriptures daily, to see whether these things are true.

The Apostle Paul is telling us to check out what people say as it relates to the Bible to see if what they are saying conforms to what the Scriptures say and teach. (Acts 17:11).

Again, I could not agree more.

The Jehovah Witnesses teach in their NWT of the Bible that Jesus Christ is "a god" at John 1:1.

At Isaiah 7:14 is a prophecy

> Therefore, Jehovah himself will give you a sign: Look! The young woman* will become pregnant and will give birth to a son,+ and she will name him Im·manʹu·el

(Immanuel meaning literally "God" or "Jehovah with us." since Jehovah is the only God).

The Apostle Matthew at Matthew 1:23 quotes Isaiah 7:14,

> “Look! The virgin will become pregnant and will give birth to a son, and they will name him Im·manʹu·el,”+ which means, when translated, “With Us Is God.”+

Isaiah also says at Isaiah 43:10-11,

> "You are My witnesses, declares the Lord, And my servant whom I have chosen, In order that you may know and believe Me, and understand that I am He, Before Me there was no God formed, And there will be none after Me. vs11, "I, even I, am the Lord; and there is no savior besides Me."

I believe since  there is no other God except for Jehovah, which even the Jehovah Witnesses attest too, that Jesus Christ and God the Father are one and the same being who are equal in nature/essence, power and eternal yet distinct in persons.

Then there is Isaiah 9:6

> For a child will be born to us, a son will be given to us; And the government will rest on His shoulders; And His name will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal Father, Prince of Peace."

The Son, Jesus Christ in this verse is identified as "Mighty God."

Isaiah 10:21 says,

> Only a remnant will return,

> The remnant of Jacob, to the Mighty God.+

Also Jeremiah 32:18.

> O great and mighty God, The Lord of hosts is His name."

Obviously there cannot be two mighty Gods because for the Witnesses there is only one true God as Isaiah 45:22 and of course John 17:3 inform us.

Which viewpoint of "ACCURATE" knowledge of God and His Son does not contradict God's word?

Is it Matthew 1:23 which says
“God with us?"

Or is it John 1:1 in the NWT that teaches "a god" is with us in the form of a created creature known as Jesus Christ and His role as Michael the arc-angel?

Comment: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002152

Comment: Jw full explanation on this is found here https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1970247

Answer (score 4):

The name Im·manʹu·el means "With Us Is God", and Jehovahs Witneses (JWs) believe that is the translation of that name [it-1 pp. 1187-1189](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002152?q=immanuel&p=par).

Not necessarily everyone with that name is a god, but we also consider the meaning of the name to be true in the case of Jesus. Jesus is a God, but we do not consider him to be equal or the same as Jehovah or Yahweh. (To avoid any confusion about where Lord refers to Jesus and where it refers to Jehovah i will use the ASV here.)

> Isaiah 43:10-11 10 Ye are my witnesses, saith Jehovah, and my servant
> whom I have chosen; that ye may know and believe me, and understand
> that I am he: before me there was no God formed, neither shall there
> be after me. 11I, even I, am Jehovah; and besides me there is no
> saviour. (ASV)

We believe that the titles mentioned in Isaiah 9:6: “His name will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal Father, Prince of Peace" all apply to Jesus. Note that it was not written almighty God, and note that a prince is typically defined as a son of the king.
The "mighty" god in Isaiah 9:6 is a translation of 'El Gib·bohr' not of 'El Shad·dai' (Almighty). We there fore do not consider the word mighty, or the combination 'mighty god' to have the necessity to be uniquely used for Jehovah God, although it can also be used for Jehovah God. More information about what JW's believe about the difference between mighty and Almighty can be read in [it-1 pp. 77-79](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200000201?q=mighty%20god&p=par)

Comment: Can it be said, Jehovah's witnesses are not monotheists then?

Comment: @Anixx   No https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1986491

Comment: Comments should be for clarification about how a point answers the question if it isn’t clear. Please do not use the comment box using terms that may be looked out as being worded in bad taste on another’s comment. Be polite to others.

Comment: @Anixx, No because we only worship Jehovah God (Mat 4:10). Jesus is very important to us, we pray to the Father (Jehovah) in his Jesus name (John 16:23). We believe than no one can enter heaven without knowing, believing and following Jesus. But we do not worship Jesus. We consider him the way to the Father, not the destination (John 14:6).

Comment: @JWsa polytheism does not require worshipping several gods, only admitting there are. You can worship only Zeus but is you admit his progeny is also divine, you are a polytheist.

Comment: @Anixx  I understand your assertion based in a strict definition of the word polytheist. JWs believe that there is only one eternally existing uncreated being. That is of course the Almighty God Jehovah.  All other beings in heaven and on earth are created by Jehovah. When one of those beings is spoken of as a god in the scriptures it is always applied to describe a position of superiority over other created beings. For example 2Cor 4:4 says that Satan is the god of this world.    Would any Christian who believes that verse is true also be a polytheist?

Comment: @Kris well, I think in ancient Greek religion there was also only one eternally existing uncreated being.

Comment: @Kris Satan is a "so called" god. 1 Corinthians 8:5, "For even if there are so-called gods whether in heaven or on earth, as indeed there are many gods and many lords, vs6, yet for us there is one God, the Father from whom are all things, and we exist for Him; and one Lord, Jesus Christ, by whom are all things and we exist through Him." You quote 2 Corinthians 4:4 but ignore the last part, that they might not see the light of the gospel of the glory of Christ, WHO IS THE IMAGE OF GOD." How is Jesus Christ the "image" of God is explained at Hebrews 1:3. The exact representation of His nature.

Comment: http://jehovah.to/exe/general/monotheism.htm.

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/77922/23657 related to the polytheism comments

Answer (score 4):

Although "Insight on the Scriptures" was published in 1988, and Jehovah's Witnesses [JWs] are encouraged to use Watchtower Society literature produced after 2000, it's good to see that a JW here uses that 1988 volume. Yes, it replaced the 1971 "Aid to Bible Understanding" but I have both volumes and there is not even a word of difference between the two (under the heading 'Immanuel'). Most of the 11 paragraphs deal with identifying characters in the Hebrew scriptures who might have been named Immanuel.

The Insight book says:

> "Immanuel is a name-title applied to Christ the Messiah."
> https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002152?q=immanuel&p=par p.1187

A very subtle result of the Insight article is that the meaning "God ***is*** with us" allows the JW mind-set to keep away from the idea of God in Christ. This is just a title (is the inference) that indicates a second-person abstraction, an association of the idea of God being with his people through Christ representing him. Whereas, if the name means that the person bearing that name is God, then Matthew 1:23 is effectively calling Christ 'God'.

That is why the Insight book is careful to state:

> "The identity of Jesus Christ as Immanuel did not mean he was the
> incarnation of God, 'God in the flesh,' which proponents of the
> Trinity teaching claim is implied by the meaning of Immanuel..." (*ibid* p.1188)

Ah, but here a subtle detail is slipped in. Instead of saying trinitarians take the meaning of Immanuel to be 'God with us', (as they do), the JW meaning is inserted instead - 'With us is God' - which is ***not*** how trinitarians put it.