Why do Jehovah's Witness not consider Jesus to be God when St. Paul says He is the Savior?
Given the scripture which says:

But what does it say? "The Word is near you, in your mouth and in your heart--that is, the word of faith which we are preaching, that if you confess with your mouth Jesus as Lord and believe in your heart that God raised Him from the dead, you shall be saved.  for with the heart man believes, resulting in righteousness, and with the mouth he confesses, resulting in salvation. For the Scriptures says, "Whoever believes in Him will not be disappointed. For there is no distinction between Jew and Greek; for THE SAME LORD is Lord of all, abounding in riches for all who call upon Him; for "Whoever will call upon the name of the Lord will be saved."
Romans 10:8-13

and

to the church of God which is at Corinth, to those who have been sanctified in Christ Jesus, saints by calling, with all who in every place call upon the name of OUR LORD JESUS CHRIST, their Lord and ours.
1 Corinthians 1:2,

Since Jehovah's Witnesses explicitly teach that Jesus Christ is "a god" who was created, on what basis is he able to save billions of people by calling upon "a god"?
How can you claim that you are saved by way of "a god"?

We do not teach that Jesus Christ is a created human being

Does this answer your question? If Jesus is "a god" would not Jehovah’s Witnesses be polytheists?

Or this? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/97270/23657

Or this? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/79644/23657

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/78481/23657

I corrected my statement. Secondly, I'm specifically asking how can Jesus Christ be THE LORD who saves billions of people as opposed to you saying he's "a god?" How can a god save anybody?

Or this https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/94203/23657

as Jesus’ followers came to know their Master, it is apparent that their use of the title “Lord” expressed much more than simple respect.  https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1994407

The NWT study notes on Romans 10:9 says the following about Jesus being called Lord:

Lord: The Greek word used here, Kyʹri·os (Lord), is generally used as a noun in the Scriptures. Strictly speaking, it is an adjective
signifying the possessing of power (kyʹros) or authority. It appears
in every book of the Christian Greek Scriptures except in Paul’s
letter to Titus and the letters of John. As God’s created Son and
Servant, Jesus Christ properly addresses his Father and God (Joh
20:17) as “Lord” (Kyʹri·os), the One having superior power and
authority, his Head. (Mt 11:25; 1Co 11:3) However, the title “Lord,”
as used in the Bible, is not limited to Jehovah God. It is also used
with reference to Jesus Christ (Mt 7:21; Ro 1:4, 7), one of the
heavenly elders seen by John in vision (Re 7:13, 14), angels (Da
12:8), humans (Ac 16:16, 19, 30; here rendered “masters” or “sirs”),
and false deities (1Co 8:5). Some claim that the phrase “Jesus is
Lord” means that he and his Father, Jehovah, are the same person.
However, the context makes it clear that this cannot be the case,
since “God raised [Jesus] up from the dead.” Jesus’ authority as Lord
was given to him by the Father.​—Mt 28:18; Joh 3:35; 5:19, 30.​—See
study note on that Jesus is Lord in this verse.
that Jesus is Lord: While Jesus was on earth, some who were not his
followers called him “Lord,” using the term as a title of respect or
courtesy. When the Samaritan woman called him “Sir,” it was also out
of respect. The Greek word used by Bible writers (Kyʹri·os) has a wide
range of meaning and can, depending on the context, be rendered “Sir,”
“Master,” or “Lord.” (Mt 8:2; Joh 4:11) However, Jesus indicated that
by calling him Lord, his disciples (or learners) showed that they
recognized him as their Master, or Lord. (Joh 13:13, 16) Especially
after Jesus’ death and resurrection to an exalted position in heaven
did his title Lord take on greater significance. By means of his
sacrificial death, Jesus purchased his followers and thus became both
their Owner (1Co 7:23; 2Pe 2:1; Jude 4; Re 5:9, 10) and their King
(Col 1:13; 1Ti 6:14-16; Re 19:16). Acknowledging Jesus as Lord
involves more than simply calling him by that title. True Christians
must recognize his position and obey him.​—Mt 7:21; Php 2:9-11.

On the use of the term Lord in Romans 10:12 the NWT study notes say the following:

Lord: The identity of the one referred to as “Lord” (Kyʹri·os) in this
verse cannot be established with certainty from the context; nor have
Bible scholars come to an agreement as to whether Paul meant the Lord
Jesus Christ or the Lord Jehovah. Ro 10:9 clearly refers to Jesus
Christ as Lord, and the quotation from Isa 28:16 found at Ro 10:11
applies to him as well. So if the “Lord” at Ro 10:12 is to be directly
linked with “him” at Ro 10:11, the “Lord” referred to is Jesus Christ.
On the other hand, at Ro 10:9, Paul speaks of exercising faith ‘in
your heart’ that “God raised him up from the dead.” Furthermore, Ro
10:13, a quotation from Joe 2:32, states: “Everyone who calls on the
name of Jehovah will be saved.” Hence, if the “Lord” referred to at Ro
10:12 is the same as at Ro 10:13, Jehovah God is the “Lord” being
referred to. The thought would then be the same as that expressed at
Ro 3:29​—there is one God over both Jews and Gentiles. This is an
example of how the New World Bible Translation Committee examined the
context of each occurrence of the word Kyʹri·os (Lord) to determine
where to restore the divine name. If the Hebrew Scripture background
and the context provide no clear support for restoring the divine
name, the committee retained the rendering “Lord” so as not to
overstep the bounds of a translator, venturing into the field of
interpretation.​

As for 1. Corinthians 1:2 you can find the following explanation in JW Literature:

[As for] Paul’s words at 1 Corinthians 1:2, where he mentioned “all who
everywhere are calling upon the name of our Lord, Jesus Christ.” One
should note, however, that in the original language, the expression
“to call upon” can mean things other than prayer.
How was the name of Christ ‘called upon’ everywhere? One way was that
the followers of Jesus of Nazareth openly acknowledged him to be the
Messiah and “Savior of the world,” performing many miraculous acts in
his name. (1 John 4:14; Acts 3:6; 19:5) Therefore, The Interpreter’s
Bible states that the phrase “to call on the name of our Lord . . .
means to confess his lordship rather than to pray to him.”
Accepting Christ and exercising faith in his shed blood, which make
the forgiveness of sins possible, also constitute a “calling upon the
name of our Lord, Jesus Christ.” (Compare Acts 10:43 with Acts 22:16.)
And we literally say Jesus’ name whenever we pray to God through him.
So, while showing that we can call upon the name of Jesus, the Bible
does not indicate that we should pray to him.​—Ephesians 5:20;
Colossians 3:17.

As JWs hold that Jehovah God created everything THROUGH Jesus (koine greek word „dia“ being used everywhere where Jesus‘ activity in creation is described) there is no problem for them holding that Jesus, as a mighty spirit (a god) that had a beginning from God Almighty, is the cause of our existence.
As for Jesus being called Savior, JW Literature states:

Repeatedly the Scriptures refer to God as Savior. At Isaiah 43:11 God
even says: “Besides me there is no savior.” Since Jesus is also
referred to as Savior, are God and Jesus the same? Not at all. Titus
1:3, 4 speaks of “God our Savior,” and then of both “God the Father
and Christ Jesus our Savior.” So, both persons are saviors. Jude 25
shows the relationship, saying: “God, our Savior through Jesus Christ
our Lord.” (Italics added.) (See also Acts 13:23.) At Judges 3:9, the
same Hebrew word (moh·shiʹa‛, rendered “savior” or “deliverer”) that
is used at Isaiah 43:11 is applied to Othniel, a judge in Israel, but
that certainly did not make Othniel Jehovah, did it? A reading of
Isaiah 43:1-12 shows that verse 11 means that Jehovah alone was the
One who provided salvation, or deliverance, for Israel; that salvation
did not come from any of the gods of the surrounding nations.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
